# How to get php code to be executed within opencpu package

Tags: php, r, opencpu

I'm using R with the R package `opencpu` to serve results of code. I would like to get my pages to be served as php and not just standard http. Currently, a standard `inst/www/info.php` like

```
<?php
phpinfo(); 
?>
```

is not interpreted, firefox just offer to download it.

I tried to activate php in nginx, also to follow [this](http://syshell.net/2013/11/02/opencpu-utilizzo-tramite-php/) but still can get a php page to be interpreted. This is blocking for my current project that needs interactions in php with the server.

Comment: @Gregor opencpu is an R package

Comment: My mistake! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't run php code inside opencpu because it runs in R. However the standard cloud server installation uses the default apache2 webserver under `/ocpu/`. So you can put your php scripts anywhere else on the same server.